# How can I Customize My WordPress Admin Dashboard into Dark Mode?

Tags: plugins

I want to customize my all wp dashboard for my clients and I want to change the login logo, admin panel themes, disable all uneasy things and over all I want to hide my WP admin panel like no one can understand that I'm using WordPress. Is there any solutions?

Comment: are you asking for a recommendation? If so you should ask at the software recommendations stack, recommendations are offtopic here, otherwise you should clarify your question to make it clear you don't want plugin/product recommendations to avoid close votes

Comment: Note that "dark mode" generally means an alternative colour scheme for when a device is in 'dark mode'. What you're describing is "white labelling".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I'm using WP Adminify plugin for that. You can customize everything what you need for your WordPress dashboard. Check this out for more details: https://wpadminify.com

I hope you will get what you wanted :)

Comment: recommendations are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. You can use links offsite to support an answer, but the link can't _be_ the answer.